# What is the theory behind Eurocode 1 - Part 2: Traffic loads on bridges?

Tags: civil-engineering, bridges, eurocodes

I'm interested in some theory *Eurocode 1: Actions on structures - Part 2: Traffic loads on bridges*. How were the limits chosen (e.g. maximum deck acceleration = 3.50 m/s<sup>2</sup>)? Why is the lower limit of $n_0$ governed by dynamic impact criteria and given by the following?

$$n_0 = \begin{cases}
80/L, &4m<L<20m \\[2ex]
23,58L^{-0,592}, &20m<L<100m
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Do the eurocodes have commentary sections included with them? Usually these types of questions are addressed in the commentary.

Comment: @hazzey There are lots of manuals on how to apply the Eurocodes, but I have never seen a commentary such as what exists for the ASCE codes. I have found tracing down the origin of the formulas/constants in Eurocodes extremely difficult. Would be very interested if someone has compiled such information!

Comment: Since Eurocode 1: Actions on Structures - Part 2 appears to be quite lengthy, could you provide a more specific code reference? (i.e. what section number or annex is the maximum deck acceleration limit and n0 equation coming from?)